# Search and replace with regex in the replacement

Tags: regular-expression, search-replace

I would like to replace all instances of match("something") with match("something", source). However, using

```
:%s/match(.*)/match(.*,\ source)/g
```

replaces it by match(.*, source). How do I specify the string the wildcard .* points to, in the replacement part of the command?